# Lyx: Calling external script/program

Tags: knitr, lyx

I have a program that generates LaTex output. I'd like to have Lyx execute that program on the fly (much as R scripts are executed on the fly by knitr) and incorporate the LaTex output into the document. Is there a way?

The hack is to use knitr and wrap my program in some R code using system(). This works, but... it's a hack, and you have to play games to get the output to work right. If there's a clean, native Lyx solution, that would be better!

Thanks!

Comment: If your program can input a .tex file and output a .tex file, then yes, you can do this in LyX. See Help > Customization and read the section on Coverters. If your program only generates LaTeX output, you need something that will run your code and put the output of that code into the .tex file. This is what knitr does and that's why it works. Note that there are knitr engines for languages other than R. For example you can use Python. (you still need R to run it, but you can avoid the `system` hack).